# eclipse new project class not found error

Tags: java, eclipse, build, classpath

I have an existing project in java and I want to compile and run it , the project needs a JAR file which is included in the project itself, I want to compile and run from `cmd`.
the compile command from `cmd` works just fine as follows:

```
javac.exe -classpath .;"C:\Program Files\Apache ActiveMQ\activemq-all-5.2.0.jar" D:\topic\src\jms\pubsub\topic\SimpleTopicPublisher.java
```

but when I run the following command to start it shows an error of missing class:

```
java.exe -cp .;"C:\Program Files\Apache ActiveMQ\activemq-all-5.2.0.jar" jms.pubsub.topic.SimpleTopicPublisher topic1 1
```

what should I do to make it work?!

the java files of the project are in this location:

```
D:\topic\src\jms\pubsub\topic\
```

Comment: are u in the root directory, i.e you should have jms/pubsub/topic/SimpleTopicPublisher.class

Comment: which root do you mean?!

Comment: the directory from where you are running the class.

Comment: @Pankaj no because of that I used the -classpath it should do the work am I right?!

Comment: What does `dir jms/pubsub/topic/SimpleTopicPublisher.class` return? If `File Not Found` then you are in the wrong directory.

Comment: you should not put .class to run it!, and how can I add it to the classpath that is my question!

Comment: @flashdisk i did not put .class to run it. You have to add the directory which contains the `jms` directory to your classpath. (Also the `jms` directory must contain `pubsub/topic/` and the class file)

Comment: I have added anew class path variable in eclipse that contains the directory that contain jms as follow: D:\topic\src\ but it still the same!

Comment: @flashdisk Why eclipse? From your question you are working on console. Please tell us the complete path where the .class file is, then we can tell you what your classpath should look like.

Comment: here it is :D:\topic\src\jms\pubsub\topic\SimpleTopicPublisher.class

Comment: Then your classpath should be: `-cp "D:\topic\src\";"C:\Program Files\Apache ActiveMQ\activemq-all-5.2.0.jar"`

Comment: can you give me the command to run exactly?! and what does th ; mean?!

Comment: I'm a bit baffled, you used the `;` yourself! It is a separator between classpath elements, so you can add multiple directories. The complete command would be: `java.exe -cp  "D:\topic\src\";"C:\Program Files\Apache ActiveMQ\activemq-all-5.2.0.jar" jms.pubsub.topic.SimpleTopicPublisher topic1 1`

Comment: did not work it says: could not find or load main class Files\Apache

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52018/discussion-between-absurd-mind-and-flashdisk)